# Is it possible to replace the loop created from asyncio with QtAsyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pyside6

I'm trying to use the QtAsyncio library in pyside 6 and with the python-snapcast library and i can't manage to find a way to replace the asyncio loop that the create_server function necessitates with something from QtAsyncio

I tried to use QtAsyncio.run since it creates the loop by itself but the create_server function necessitates a variable with the loop.

```
server = QtAsyncio.run(create_server(ip_value))
```

this is the normal implementation with asycnio

```
server = loop.run_until_complete(create_server(loop, 'localhost'))
```

Comment: What is `create_server` that you are referring to? There is a [`loop.create_server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_server) in the `asyncio` module. That is a low-level function for creating a TCP server. The [`asyncio` streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html) module should be used for building TCP clients and servers. From the question, it isn't entirely clear what you're trying to do and why you need to replace loops. Generally speaking, one should not be managing loops, as the high-level API functions get the running loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the running loop by calling `get_running_loop`.
Just put a small wrapper around your `create_server` call to retrieve the loop:

```
import asyncio
import QtAsyncio

async def wrapper(hostname):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop
    return await create_server(loop, hostname)

...

QtAsyncio.run(wrapper("localhost"))
```